# Why is C++ still using stdio.h?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

this is probably a dumb question, but I couldnt find the answer I was looking for. Also, I was unsure if this was a C++ question or a VS2010 question, but the answer I'm looking for is that of a technical POV, so I ended up here.

When you start a new Console Application project in VS2010, it automatically includes stdafx.h, which in turn includes **stdio.h**.
The answers I found regarding stdio.h vs. iostream was more or less:

> stdio.h was used in C and iostream is
>   used in C++

I dont know if this is right or wrong, but...

**My question is:** Why is stdio.h still automatically included in C++ projects? Wouldnt iostream be sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IO streams in older C++ implementations were pretty slow, leading programmers to keep using `stdio.h`. Apparently, that got included in `stdafx.h` in the past and cannot be removed from that header anymore as removing it would break existing code.

Comment: How would removing a default for __new__ projects break existing code? At most files being dropped into newer projects would need `#include stdio.h`

Comment: If this is correct, I think it answers my question pretty accurately. In other words it's a leftover from when stdio.h was (more frequently) used for io operations than iostream in C++, and could nowadays be considered more or less obsolete for C++ programming? Also, as Yippie-Kai-Yay states, I may be better off just going for an empty project to start with. Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't use a header such as `stdafx.h` anyway. C++'s inclusion mechanism is crude enough as it is, compiler vendors shouldn't make this worse.

Comment: actually `stdafx.h` is useful for larger projects to speed up compilation time. AFAIK you can always turn it off if you don't like it.

Comment: @James: There's nothing magical about `stdafx.h`. For larger projects, you really want dedicated precompiled headers for different sub-projects. For instance, non-GUI parts may define `NOGDI`.

Answer (score 3):

Usually projects are created using `Create Empty Project`, so that you can customize your includes and precompiled headers yourself.

*I have no idea why does this "default" include happens, but it's a good thing to setup your project from scratch as I've described before.*

Answer (score 0):

Even if you're using stream output, being able to do some formatting is nice.  So, if nothing else, sprintf will sometimes be used.  sprintf lives in stdio.h

Comment: Streams have formatting. And there's Boost.Format. No need for sprintf (and you should use snprintf anyway).

Comment: Yeah, Boost... Zillion of code, insane compile errors, and what you get is Boost.Format instead printf()! Not a fair deal for hello-world.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly because visual studio targets Mort programmers, who wouldn't be able to get 'my first c++' program done without printf, and they would decide that the product didn't work right.

Before down voting plea google visual studio mort persona.